# click function in prototypejs

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

How can I write the following jquery in prototypejs?

```
<a class="button view" style="cursor:pointer" id="addComment"></a>

$(function() {
 $("#addComment").click(function(){

         alert("hello world");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/U4fCu/)

```
Event.observe('addComment', 'click', function(event) {
    alert('u clicked on click here');
});​
```